# How to count over threshold metrics from range vector in PromQL (Prometheus)

Tags: prometheus, promql

I defined `latency` metrics it can query as scalar like below:

```
latency{name="Controller/products/show",percentiles="95"}   0.9935112
```

Then, I did the query. Output is a range vector.

```
latency{name="Controller/products/show",percentiles="95"}[10m]
```

output:

```
element:
latency{name="Controller/products/show",percentiles="95"}

value:
0.9429009 @1584497778.164
0.9150374 @1584497838.164
0.9085548 @1584497898.164
0.9006939 @1584497958.164
0.9390876 @1584498018.164
0.9593425 @1584498138.164
0.96289706 @1584498198.164
0.98113775 @1584498258.164
0.9935112 @1584498318.164
```

I want to count over `0.95` values from vector range values.

For example, get `4` from above vector range values.

Anyone have solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Prometheus subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) can be used for this task:

```
count_over_time((latency{name="Controller/products/show",percentiles="95"} > 0.95)[10m:50s])
```

Note that the `step` value after the colon (`50s` in the example above) must be smaller than the scrape interval for the selected metric, since Prometheus evaluates the query inside parenthesis at regular points with the configured `step` interval between them.

Update:
This task also can be solved without subqueries when using [count_gt_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_gt_over_time) function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). For example, the following query returns the number of raw samples with values exceeding `0.95` over the last 10 minutes:

```
count_gt_over_time(latency{name="Controller/products/show",percentiles="95"}, 0.95)
```

Comment: Thank you!
I upgraded my Prom to 2.7.0 and queried your suggestion.  

I got a desired value.  

I will lean about a subquery deeply.